# SetActionView on menu Item support

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

Hi I am implementing the rotation animation of the refresh icon located on the action bar. When I run my app on newer apis everything works fine. but when I run on api 8 for example I have problems with setActionView. please help.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_refresh:

            item.setActionView(getAnimation());

            getCurrency(code,null);
            mViewpager.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.i("TAG", "refresh pressed =>");
            return true;
        }

        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

getAnimation method

```
public View getAnimation(){
        LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplication()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) inflater1.inflate(R.layout.action_refresh,
                null);
                Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.refresh_rotate);
                rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                iv.startAnimation(rotation);
                return iv;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure what is your problem, but it seems like you are using API which is not available on level 8.

Change this:

```
item.setActionView(getAnimation());
```

To this:

```
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item,getAnimation());
```